# Show attribute of other model in list_view

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following 3 models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    one = models.Charfield()
    two = models.Charfield()
    #etc

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    modelc = models.ForeignKey(ModelC)
    #etc

class ModelC(models.Model):
    five = models.Charfield()
    six = models.Charfield()
    #etc
```

I have an admin for ModelA:

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('one', 'two')
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display attribute 'five' of ModelC in the admin list view of ModelA:

```
list_display = ('one', 'two', 'five')
```

I get this error:

```
ModelAAdmin.list_display[2], 'five' is not a callable or an attribute of 'ModelAAdmin' or found in the model 'ModelA'.
```

Correct... and I understand... because the ForeignKey is not on ModelA but on ModelB.

But how can I display the attribute in the admin list view?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the list_display element a function, which takes the object as a parameter.

```
def get_five(obj):
    return ("%s") % obj.modelc.five

get_five.short_description = 'five'

class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('one', 'two', get_five)
```

Not sure if you'll be able to access modelc like that, but if not you can create a query.

Comment: create a query means it has to create it for each row... I want to avoid that

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. So if I'm understanding correctly, you want from ModelA, to display an attribute from ModelC. The relationship between ModelA and ModelC is in ModelB right? What if there's lots of ModelBs with the same ModelA as an object, but different ModelC objects?